# root login from GUI

Tags: greeter, root

Is it possible at all to login to elementary os as root.  I enabled root account by setting a password. To make root appear as one of the login accounts on the GUI login screen, what are the next steps?
Is there a file that I need to edit to let root appear in the login screen?  E.g., Ubuntu has it in /etc/gdm3 directory.  something similar in elementary ?
Thanks for your time.
Jung

Comment: Is there some problem you're trying to fix, or do you just want to be able to login as root?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "root" do you mean a user named "root" (the default sudo username) or do you just mean logging in with root privileges?

What do you need to do with a root login?

Thanks, Col

Answer (score 0):

Logging in through a graphical user interface as *root* is considered a security risk, so most display managers aren't going to cater to this.
You should almost always use `sudo` to execute commands as *root*.
If you would like a *root* shell, then on Debian-based systems such as elementaryOS, log in as your normal user and run `sudo su` from the terminal.
If you need to avoid logging in as a normal user, either boot in to emergency / single-user mode by selecting the option from the Grub menu or switch to a different, non-graphical *TTY* with *Ctrl-Alt-F2*, for example, and login that way as root.
You can switch back to the display manager with *Ctrl-Alt-F7*.

Comment: Thanks JWillikers.  I suppose all I needed was a test env without having to have a user login.  I thought elementary OS would be very similar to Ubuntu in terms of security FS.
Any how, it is not a deal breaker :)